# Do real vectors attain matrix norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

The $p$-norm of a matrix $A$ for $p \geq 1$ is defined as $$\|A\|_p = \max_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_p=1} \|Ax\|_p.$$ My question: does this equal $$ 
\max_{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n, \|x\|_p=1} \|Ax\|_p$$ The only difference is the replacement of $\mathbb R^n$ by $\mathbb C^n$. The answer is certainly yes for $p=1,2,\infty$ and the [Wikipedia article on matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) appears to imply the answer is yes for any $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is not true for the norms $\|A\|_{p,q}$.  For example, if $A = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$, $$\max_{x \in {\mathbb R}^2: \|x\|_\infty = 1} \|A x\|_1 = 2$$
but $x = \pmatrix{1\cr i\cr}$ has $\|x\|_\infty = 1$ and $\|Ax\|_1 = 2 \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the entries of $A$  are not all real, the answer may be no.  For example, consider the $2 \times 1$ matrix $A = (1 \ i)$ with $p=2$. 
$$\max_{x \in {\mathbb C}^2, \|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2 = \sqrt{2}$$ but
$$\max_{x \in {\mathbb R}^2, \|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2 = 1$$

Comment: Re "If the entries of A are all real, then the answer is yes." - Is this easy to prove? Can you add a proof to the post?

Comment: Actually I removed that claim, because I don't see a way to prove it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered looking at the wikipedia article on [Matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm)? I guess your answer is well written there. In any case, if not, then yes, it is true regardless of whether $x$ is over $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: The wikipedia article does seem to imply the two are equal, but is there an argument there to that effect? If so, I must be overlooking it.