# Norm of matrix and vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ a $n\times 1$ vector.

From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\|A x\|\leq \|A\| \|x\|$.

Is it possible to find a scalar $c$ such that it holds  $\|A x\| = c\,\|A\| \|x\| $?

If yes, what would be a requested reference to study related proofs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do real vectors attain matrix norms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103160/do-real-vectors-attain-matrix-norms)

Comment: @JacobManaker The answers were already fine, however, your link complements it, thanks.

Comment: @JacobManaker In the linked question, $\|x\|=1$. Can also other values instead of 1 be used?

Comment: For $S$ a constant and $x$ a unit vector, $$\|A\cdot Sx\|=\|S\cdot Ax\|=|S|\|Ax\|$$

Comment: @JacobManaker Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the inequality you mentioned, if such a scalar exists it must be $1$. What you are asking is for a vector $x$ for which the matrix attains its norm. In a finite dimensional space, all matrices attain their norm, whatever that norm is. That is, there will always exist some $x$ such that $\|Ax\|=\|A\|\cdot \|x\|$. However, there is no general algorithm to find that $x$. It depends on the norm, and sometimes there is no closed formula for such an $x$.

Related proofs may be found in standard texts on multivariate calculus, or elementary functional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, for example, $\mathbb R^2$ with the euclidean norm, and the matrix

$$ A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}{1\quad0\\[1.5ex]0\quad0}
\end{array}
\right].
$$

We have $\|A\|=1$ and, for $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2$:

$$ \|Ax^\mathtt t\|=\|(x_1,0)^{\mathtt t}\|=|x_1| $$

and

$$ c\,\|A\|\,\|x^{\tt t}\|=c\,\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\,. $$

If your hypothesis were true, it would be $\;c\,\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}= |x_1|$, and therefore

$$ \qquad c = \frac{|x_1|}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}} \qquad \text{ if }\; (x_1,x_2)\neq (0,0), $$

so $\;c\;$ would depend on $x$, absurd.